# Issue in making simple TCP_CLIENT

Tags: python, tcpclient

The problem is that when I run this code for making simple client then I get error like this.

```
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80

# ➊ create a socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# ➋ connect the client
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

# ➌ send some data
client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")

# ➍ receive some data
response = client.recv(4096)

print response
```

I first create a socket object with the `AF_INET` and `SOCK_STREAM` parameters ➊. The `AF_INET` parameter is saying we are going to use a standard IPv4 address or host_name, and `SOCK_STREAM` indicates that this will be a TCP client. We then connect the client to the server ➋ and send it some data ➌. The last step is to receive some data back and print out the response.

This Error occur when I run 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\engin\Desktop\TCP_client.py", line 10, in <module>
client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")  
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run Python2-Code with Python3, which would first result in a SyntaxError, because of the print-statement. Second, you have to send bytes, not strings:

```
client.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Daniel. It is working with python 2.7.